# linux new user with sftp to specific folder

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssh

Hi I have ssh connection to my server wit root account. I want to create user named `pizza4yu` and give access with `winscp` to only this location `/home/pi/apache-tomcat-7.0.35`  How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chsh -s /bin/bash pizza4yu
usermod -d /home/pi/apache-tomcat pizza4yu
chown -R pizza4yu:pizza4yu /home/pi/apache-tomcat
```

You can also use chroot: http://chrootssh.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you. If you could also explain what those commands do would appreciate. I don't know Linux so much.

Comment: 1. chsh - change shell for user to bash, so now user can use ssh (and winscp); 2. set home directory for user; 3. change owner (user:group) on directory

Answer (score 0):

Set the users home folder to that path so.

```
Usermod -d /home/pi/apache-tomcat pizza4yu
```

All in lowercase
 Then `chown -R pizza4yu /new/path` or add the new user to existing group of that folder

Comment: so I did: sudo adduser pizza4yu, then sudo groupadd sftponly,then sudo adduser pizza4yu sftponly, then sudo usermod -d /home/pi/apache-tomcat-7.0.35 pizza4yu After that the winscp connects to right folder but should I change the access somehow ? Didn't understand that chown -R part.. ? Or how can I set that group or user to use only tomcat folder ? And can I set that the pizza4yu user don't have ssh connection. Only sftp ?

Comment: Well now it works, but then further. How can I set that pizza4yu cant use shell, example putty ? I want to give that user only winscp acces. Plus I have set chmod 777 to /var/www how can I set it like the admin user has full rights and pizza4yu has no acces ?